# What is operator calculus? Article by Palais.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, manifolds, morse-theory

I'm reading a paper titled [Morse theory on Hilbert Manifolds](https://vmm.math.uci.edu/PalaisPapers/MorseThOnHilbertManifolds.pdf) by R. Palais. And in the demonstration of the Morse Lemma (pg 307), he use something called operator calculus, for example he take the characteristic function $h$ of the interval $[0,\infty)$ and simply compute it on an operator $A$, giving $h(A)=P$ where $P$ is an orthogonal projection. I really didn't understand this procedure. What does it make sense to compute $h(A)$? Can someone clarify this? Or even give me a reference?

Comment: I think it will be easy to find more than enough material on the internet using the keyword "functional calculus" (for self-adjoint operators).

Answer (score 1):

You should look up the spectral theorem for self adjoint operators. One version of it (there are several) states that every self adjoint operator $A$ on a separable Hilbert space is unitarily equivalent to a multiplication operator on some Hilbert space (equipped with a possibly different measure). So to be more precise, let $A$ be a self adjoint operator on $H$, then there exists a non-negative Borel measure $\mu$ and a unitary operator $U$ such that $$U: H \to L^2(\mu)$$ and $$A_{\phi}=UAU^{-1}$$

Where $(A_{\phi}f)(x)=\phi(x)f(x)$

Now you can define what is known as functional calculus. Let $g$ be a Borel function then define $g(A)$ to be:

$$g(A):=U^{-1}A_{g \circ \phi}U$$

In simple terms, if $A$ is realized as the multiplication operator by $\phi$ on $L^2(\mu)$ then $g(A)$ is simply the multiplication operator by $g \circ \phi$ on that space.

The above could be generalized to the non-separable case as well.